# I can't use ActiveUp.MailSystem.Net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, email, namespaces

I'm trying to use `ActiveUp.MailSystem.Net` which I downloaded from here:

https://mailsystem.codeplex.com/

I added all the dll-s through the add reference option. Now `Using ActiveUp`, `Using ActiveUp.Net` are working, but for the `Using ActiveUp.Net.Mail` I get the error `The type or namespace name 'Mail' does not esist in....`. I also added the dll-s to the resources but no luck. What makes me that noob?

P.S.: I'm using Visual Studio Express C# 2010